# how to send a file in multipart formdata in pytest?

Tags: python, api, docker, swagger, mongoengine

I'm trying to write a testfile.py using pytest framework to my photo service.

My photo service is written in swagger as the following. It uses a post method to post a picture with additional information as a multipart-formdata :

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Photo service API
  version: "0.1"

paths:
  /photo:
    post:
      tags:
        - "Photo"
      operationId: photo_service.post_photo
      summary: Add a new photo
      consumes:
         - multipart/form-data
         - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
      parameters:
        - name: photo_name
          in: formData
          description: "file to upload"
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: user_id
          in: formData
          description: "user who posted"
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: photo_tags
          in: formData
          description: "tags of the photo"
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
          minimum: 1
          maximum: 30
          required: true
        - name: photo_file
          in: formData
          description: "file to upload"
          required: true
          type: file
          minLength: 1
          maxLength: 5000000
      responses:
        201:
          description: New photo added
          schema:
            properties:
              photo_file:
                  type: object
                  description: Information about the photo (size, file name, etc.)
          headers:
            Location:
              type: string
              description: The URL of the newly-added photo
        409:
          description: Photo already exists
```

My photo after this is stored in a mongodb data base. The class photo is defined as :

```
class Photo(Document):
    photo_name = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    user_id = StringField(max_length=120, required=True)
    photo_file = ImageField()
    photo_tags= ListField(StringField(max_length=30))
```

My main question is how to write a post method to test my API in a testfile.py ? I tried to write it like this:

```
headers_content_form_data = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
headers_content_json = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
headers_accept  = {'Accept': 'application/json'}

with open('/home/user/photoapp/src/ms/photo/img1.jpg', 'rb') as img1:
  imgStringIO1 = StringIO(img1.read())

@staticmethod
def test_post_once(client):
    print(os.getcwd())
    response = client.post('/photo', headers=TestClass.headers_content_form_data,
                          data={'photo_name': 'thedoors',
                                'user_id': 'laurea',
                                'photo_file': (imgStringIO1, 'img1.jpg'),
                                'photo_tags': ['testTag','45','46']
                                })
    assert response.headers['Location']
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

I seems that i am having a problem to submit the photo_file. The photo file that i tried to submit is in my local directory, the same as the one of the test file.

Also i wanna try running this inside of a container. How can i do to send my image file from my local machine to the container to run the test ?